# How Should I Disambiguate Symbols for Type Placeholders and the Free Monoid Operator?

Tags: type-theory

I've been writing [kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) using asterisk * as a placeholder for a type. For example  `→ *` is the kind of all functions of time. This was fine until I needed to use the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) operator *. I was thinking that I could write the free monoid as ٭ (the arabic five pointed star), but maybe there's a better option. What's a good way to disambiguate type placeholders and the free monoid operator?